# How to create a custom post type with additional fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

Beginner's question:
Looking for example how to create a custom post type with additional elements. What I mean is: in my code I have a basic stuff like 'title', 'editor' ... but I need also for example 'start', 'end' - date fields or 'color'.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`add_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) ([*see also User Contributed Notes for examples*](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/#user-contributed-notes)) to add custom fields to your [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). If you don't feel like adding the metaboxes by yourself, you can also use a custom fields plugin (E.g. Advanced Custom Fields, CMB2, Pods, Carbon Fields.. *I'm not affiliated to any of these*) to do it for you.

There are good articles, with code examples, about [custom meta fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) and [custom post types](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) on the developer handbook. You should check them out.

If you need to group the custom posts or do sorting or searching based on the extra information (color, maybe?), then consider using [custom taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) instead.

Comment: Ooh thank you Antti, and no no no, I don't want use any plugins, I would like to learn how to do it programatically. :P